# 3rd normal form

Tags: sql, database, forms, dependencies, normalization

I have a problem. I have a database named `Books`. And then I have 2 columns `isbn` (id of book) and `title`. Both of them are unique and they depend on each other. Is it 3NF?

I know that 3NF requires every non-key attribute should depend on they key, but I don't know what's the answer in this situation. I asked for help chatGPT but it didn't help me so...

Comment: As the ISBN is an external ID and is not a key in your database, I'd say that having it alongside the book title is 3NF compliant.

Comment: Book titles are not unique in the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you say "Both of them are unique and they depend on each other", you have 2 keys (each consisting of a single attribute) and there no non-prime attributes at all.  Hence your schema is in 3NF.

In addition, you might want to reconsider the claim that "ISBN" could reasonably be functionally dependent on "book title".  The book titled "Introduction to database systems" (a classic in the field) has had 8 different editions, and I'm pretty certain those editions all have a different ISBN, while title stayed the same.

Comment: Much appreciated. It was really helpful